# Implementing the ExtraPutty.dll into c# Program

Tags: c#, .net, dll, putty

I am trying to use funcitonalities of ExtraPutty in my c# Program.
ExtraPutty provides a dll and even sample Programs in c# for that.

The sample doesn't work for me. When the sample program calls one of the extraputty functions, I get this error message: "The Program cannot be started, because lua53.dll is missing. Install the programm again to solve this problem."

I put the dll into the output folder and
I tried to install the dll, but Windows doesnt recognize it as a valid dll. 
I used

regsrv32 /i c:\path\lua53.dll

and get this Error Message: "The Modul was loaded, but the dllRegisterServer-EntryPoint was not found. Make sure it is a valid dll or ocx file and repeat."

What is wrong with the dll? How can I install it properly?

Then I made my own program:
I don't get the dll errors but I didn't get the functionalities yet. 
I guess I make something wrong at the import and the datatypes.
I am sending the command "Unanme -r" which should return some version number of the target os. But nothing is returned.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace ExtraPuttyDLL_Test
{
  class Program
{
    [DllImport("C:\\Users\\xroeseners\\Desktop\\ExtraPuTTY-0-29\\ExtraPuTTY.dll", EntryPoint = "Connexion")]
    static extern int OpenConnection(   string TargetName, 
                                        ref UInt32 ConnectionId, 
                                        string Login, 
                                        string Password, 
                                        byte ShowTerminal, 
                                        Int32 Protocol, 
                                        UInt32 PortNumber, 
                                        Int32 Report, 
                                        CallbackRcvData Callback, 
                                        UInt32 SpecSettings);

    [DllImport("C:\\Users\\xroeseners\\Desktop\\ExtraPuTTY-0-29\\ExtraPuTTY.dll", EntryPoint = "SendRcvData")]
    static extern int SendData( UInt32 ConnectionId, 
                                string Data, 
                                string Title, 
                                string Comments,                     
                                Int32 TimeCapture, 
                                char[] Buf, 
                                Int32 MaxSizeData, 
                                UInt32 settings);
    // int SendRcvData(unsigned long ConnectionId,char *Command,char *Title,char *Comments,long TimeCapture,char **DataRcv,long MaxSizeofData,unsigned long settings);
    // Settings Bit fields of settings (2^0 : CRLF (0 send,1 not send),2^1 : Virtual key codes (0 no virtual key codes in command,1 yes)...reserved)
    // See FAQ page for a description of all virtual keys codes.  



    [DllImport("C:\\Users\\xroeseners\\Desktop\\ExtraPuTTY-0-29\\ExtraPuTTY.dll", EntryPoint = "CloseConnexion")]
    static extern int CloseSession(UInt32 ConnectionId);

    public static UInt32 myConnectionId;

    public delegate int CallbackRcvData(UInt32 ConnectionId, IntPtr Data, Int32 size, Int32 Status);

    public static string myString;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myConnectionId = new UInt32();

        int size, status;
        char[] data = null;

        CallbackRcvData Callback = new CallbackRcvData(RcvData);
        //CallbackRcvData = new CallbackRcvData(myConnectionId, 

        OpenConnection("192.168.8.98",
           ref myConnectionId,
           "admin", // user
           "admin",      // password
           0,   // no display of putty terminal
           1,       // SSH Protocol
           22,      // Port
           0,       // Generate Report: 0 =  nein
           Callback,
           0);         // bin_000 -> dont wait login prompt, dynamically starting putty log, ssh v1 otherwise ssh v2


        SendData(myConnectionId,
                "uname -r",
                "",
                "",
                5000,
                data,
                20000,
                0);



        CloseSession(myConnectionId);

    }


    public static int RcvData(UInt32 ConnectionId, IntPtr Data, Int32 size, Int32 Status)
    {
        if ((size > 0) && (Status == 0) && (Data != null))
        {
            myString = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(Data) ;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}



  }
```

Comment: I forgot to add the declarations of SendData etc.
int SendRcvData(unsigned long ConnectionId,char *Command,char *Title,char *Comments,long TimeCapture,char **DataRcv,long MaxSizeofData,unsigned long settings);

int Connexion(char *TargetName,unsigned long *ConnectionId,char *Login,char *Password,bool ShowPuTTY,long Protocol,unsigned long PortNumber,long GenerateReport,int *CallBackRcvData,unsigned long SpecSettings);

Answer (score 0):

> What is wrong with the dll?

Nothing really. It's just no COM dll.

> How can I install it properly?

Normally, you put it next to your assembly that needs it. Just the same as the ExtraPuTTY.dll. Don't use absolute paths, especially not if they are pointing to your user profile.

Comment: That's what I did. I put the dll file next to the exe file.

The code is not related to that. 
With the test code, you are right, I will put the dll into the project. 
(But I don't have that problem in my own test code).